# How to use #import on oleaut32.dll from windows32 for 64bit project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, 64-bit

I have this big visual studio solution that is currently on 32 bits (x86) for an application that uses Standard Windows Libraries,uses Multi-Byte Character Set and has No Common Language Runtime Support.I was tasked to compile it on 64 bits(stuff for work).I want to import `oleaut32.dll` library because it is on 64 bits.

When i started to change the platform of the project and compile it,I got some compilation errors(32 bit functions ,linking problems) ,most of them are solved now.The issue is that it imported olepro32.dll (which worked on 32bits),it says it is an old format or invalid type library (because it is a 32 bit library).

I searched the internet for it's 64 bits version and found out it is oleaut32.dll.I tried to import it ,but it won't let me i get error C1083:
 `c:\windows\system32\oleaut32.dll': Error loading type library/DLL`.

I tried to change the project properties(Changed from: `No Common Language Runtime Support`  **to** `Common Language Runtime Support`,it didn't work ).

I looked on microsoft website for the causes of error C1083 ,where I suspected the issues were:

1. Third-party library issues and Vcpkg
2. The file may be locked or in use
3. The wrong version of a file name is included
4. The precompiled headers are not yet precompiled
5. The file uses managed code, but the compiler option /clr is not
   specified. For more information, see /clr (Common Language Runtime
   Compilation)
6. The file, the directory, or the disk is read-only
7. Visual Studio or the command line tools do not have sufficient
   permissions to read the file or the directory.

I tried running visual studio with administrator privilages ,it didn't work.

I found out it is a COM library,I don't know what's the deal with it.

**On x86 platform the code was**:

```
#import  <olepro32.dll> rename("FONTSIZE", "FONTSIZE_OLE32") no_auto_exclude include("IFont", "IPicture")
```

**On x64 platform** I tried to replace the code above with:

```
#import  <oleaut32.dll> rename("FONTSIZE", "FONTSIZE_OLE32") no_auto_exclude include("IFont", "IPicture")
```

I was expecting that this would run smoothly since oleaut32.dll is a 64 bit library situated in windows32 folder.But I get `Error loadin DLL`

Answer (score 0):

oleaut32.dll has no relation with olepro32.dll and is not a Typelib

olepro32.dll is a TypeLib and exposes **IPicture** and **IFont** interfaces

You include those interfaces with :

```
#include <ocidl.h>
```